# problema con imagen en el carousel de bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

tengo un problema con el carousel de bootstrap y es que las imagenes no se colocan al 100% con el carousel, tengo entendido que una imagen de 1000x400 debria de verse correctamente pero en mi caso para lo siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid " src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar css para manejar el width y el height;

**EDIT**

```css
.carousel-inner .img-fluid{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


         <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid " src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/400/" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: sigue el problema @LuisFernando

Comment: no es recomendable usar el  !important

Comment: esa es mi respuesta :/

Answer (score 3):

bueno tu problema esta en las class :

```
.carousel-item .img-fluid
```

El fragmento de código del carrusel provisto en la documentación de Bootstrap 4 tiene la clase .img-fluid, lo que requeriría el uso de imágenes de gran tamaño que se reduzcan al tamaño del dispositivo móvil. Esto puede hacer que sus páginas se carguen más despacio de lo necesario.

lo unico que necesitas es agregarle un width de 100% a img-fluid que es la class de la imagen y carousel-item para darle un 100% al div(contenedor de la imagen) dandole este siguiente codigo css ,se solucionaria el problema :

```css
 
.carousel-item .img-fluid {
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placehold.it/400x200" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placehold.it/400x200" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://placehold.it/400x200" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva.